# flutter macOS build error: accessing build database disk I/O error ** BUILD FAILED **

Tags: flutter, macos, build

I received the following error while trying to build my Flutter project for MacOS,

```
error: accessing build database "..." disk I/O error 
** BUILD FAILED **
```

I tried running `flutter clean` and invalidating caches and restarting in Android Studio and IntelliJ, but it didn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have Google Drive Desktop syncing your desktop, make sure you don't sync the folder you're developing in. Either pause the sync or move the development folder outside of wherever Google Drive is syncing.